# Hadoop / HDInsight for replacing SANs?

Tags: hadoop, azure-hdinsight

Hadoop is more commonly used for querying specific information from huge amount of data I find from the internet.But I want to explore HDFS to be able to replace costly SANs..? Can you give some information regarding this, or good articles regarding the same?

Answer (score 0):

you can replace SANS with HDFS. HDFS is better than SANs because it is cheaper, also the multiple machines handle read and write request, thus scalability will be better than SANs. But maintenance of hadoop cluster may be higher than SANs.

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested in a few posts we wrote about HDFS vs. S3 and Hadoop on-premise vs. cloud:

http://www.xplenty.com/blog/2014/03/storing-apache-hadoop-data-cloud-hdfs-vs-s3/
http://www.xplenty.com/blog/2014/03/hadoop-service-vs-premise-finish-him/